# JQuery $.Get function not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Here is my JQuery code.

```
function markread(ID) {
    $.get("markread.php?id="+ID);
}
```

And here is my html

```
<div id='notificationitem-3' class='notificationitem'>
    <div class='notificationpic'>
        <img src='sadf' />
    </div>
    <div class='notmessage'><a href='asdf' onClick="markread(3);">Mark Ross has sent you a friend request.</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The get request does not go through unless there is an alert(""); after it. Why is this?

Comment: when you click ur a tag, does it redirect to other page? if yes, i think you mush prevent it. by using e.preventDefault(). take time to read this http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/.

Comment: `$.get` is expecting you to do something with the returned data.  Jquery is not that intuitive.

Comment: I want it to load to the other page after markread(3);

Comment: So what must i change it to then?

Comment: @Kingofslowmo: What text does `markread.php` return for a GET request?

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer it doesnt return anything. It simply runs a mysql query.

Comment: @Kingofslowmo: so are you saying markread.php is never hit at all?  Or are you asking what to do afterwards?

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer Okay, the jquery doesnt run markread.php unleses i add an alert after the markread.php is loaded.

Comment: @Kingofslowmo: Thanks.  So the question is why a simple line like `$.get("markread.php?id="+ID);` simply does not execute.

Comment: Exactly! Thats what i'm saying.

Comment: @Kingofslowmo: what jquery versions are you using?  I recommend you put that at the top of your post.  It's possible "required" parameters may have changed for the `get` function between jquery versions.

Answer (score 0):

since you are giving on click to `a` tag so you need to prevent the default behavior otherwise location changes aborting ajax operation 
check this out

```
function markread(e,ID) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $.get("markread.php?id="+ID, function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
        alert('Load was performed.');
       location.href   = $('.notmessage').closest('a').attr('href');
   });
}
```

Comment: but i dont want the alert.

Comment: While this is close, the parameters `e` and `ID` aren't explained (they won't work with the arguments passed in the OP's HTML code), so `e` won't be what's expected. And `e.preventDefault` isn't available in all browsers. jQuery event handlers fix both of these problems

Answer (score -1):

An Awful solution to this problem would be to set the location in the JS function and not using href.

```
function markread(ID, gohere)
{
       $.get("markread.php?id="+ID,
               function(data)
               {
                     window.location.href = gohere;
               }
       );
}
```

just add the link as a second argument

Comment: If you're admitting this is an "Awful solution to this problem", why would you suggest it when it could be done in a cleaner/better way? This doesn't fix the problem anyways - the event's default behavior needs to be prevented (so the link isn't visited immediately, canceling the AJAX request)